# Difference between a list comprehension and a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n=input()
y=n.split()
a=([int(x) for x in y])
print(a)
```

output

```
python .\input_into_list.py
1 2 3
[1, 2, 3]
```

The above output is what I wanted.

However, if I change the code a little bit, I am expecting the same output, but getting a different output.

CODE

```
n=input()
y=n.split()
for x in y:
    a=([int(x)])
print(a)
```

output

```
python .\input_into_list.py
1 2 3
[3]
```

Please explain the difference between line 3 in the first code block, and line 3 and line 4 of the second code block.

Comment: Your loop essentially does `a = [1]`, `a = [2]`, `a = [3]`…

Comment: Above is correct and about your first code, that is list comprehension which does operation on elements of list keeping list in same format(size)

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.

Answer (score 3):

The first example is what you call a list comprehension. It creates a list based on your values in a sequence and in this case your input `y`. List comprehensions are encouraged because of its simplicity and explicit purpose which returns you a list.

```
a = [int(x) for x in y]
```

Your second example is a `for` loop, loops, unlike the list comprehension, can be used for iterating through your sequence and perform multiple complex tasks. However, in your example variable `a` constantly gets updated with the latest value in `y`.

```
for i in y:
    print(i)
    a = [i]
```

To achieve the same result as a list comprehension:

```
a = []
for i in y:
    print(i)
    a.append(i)
```

To keep it short, if you are planning to return a list, do it with a list comprehension when possible. For Python as for any language, there is no hard-and-fast rule, so use your discretion with keeping efficiency and readability in mind.

Answer (score 0):

in the first script, you are adding all the values to a in a single line.

in the second script, you are reassigning a on each loop.

try to append to a instead.

```
n=input()
y=n.split()
a = []
for x in y:
    a.append(int(x))
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first code block, you create the list and after that you name it as `a`.
In the second code block, you change the value of `a` for every iteration through loop. For the second code to work, you have to do this  :

```
n=input()
a=[]

y=n.split()
for x in y:
    a.append(int(x)) 
print(a)
```

EDIT

```
n=input()
a=[]

y=n.split()
   for x in y:
      a.append(int(x)) # Remove brackets [] that means that you append a list in a list

for i in a:
   print(i) # or print(i,end='') if you want to print it in one line
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is in *appearance* and *runtime speed*. List comprehension is **shorter**, **easier to understand** and **faster in execution time**.

In your code if you want to make it same as list comprehension you need to append each element to the list:

```
n=input()
y=n.split()
a=[]
for x in y:
    a.append(int(x))
print(a)
```

this will give you the same result as list comprehension one. In addition `n.split()` method itself returning the input as a list of elements. So:

```
n=input()
y=n.split()
print(y)
```

this is the same as above one. Just a last comment, when you use *list comprehension* or another list assigning you don't need to wrap the element to the brackets like: `()`

```
n=input()
y=n.split()
a=[int(x) for x in y]
print(a)
```

Answer (score -3):

This is indentation error:

```
n=input()
y=n.split()
for x in y:
    a=([int(x)])
    print(a,end=' ')
```

Comment: n=input()
y=n.split()
for x in y:
    a=([int(x)])
print(a) >>> if this line is secured cannot we get same output

Comment: I don't understand what that means. But even changing the indentation of `print`, you don't get an equivalent output.

Comment: Yep, which isn't the same as what you'd get from a list comprehension