# difference between list comprehension and for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

There is a question with exactly the same title in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52961311/difference-between-a-list-comprehension-and-a-for-loop) but the problem is not what I want to ask. I was solving a [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/) and found there is a quite interesting difference between the list comprehension and for loop. Please compare the following two approaches.

## Approach 1

```
set1 = [[]]
num = [1,2,3]
for n in num:
    for s in set1:
        set1 += [ s + [n] ]
print(set1)
```

## Approach 2

```
set1 = [[]]
num = [1,2,3]
for n in num:
    set1 += [ s + [n] for s in set1]
print(set1)
```

`Approach 1` hangs while `Approach 2` does not and produces a correct result. The reason I think is that:
1) `Approach 1` adds element to set1 for each member of set1. Thus, the for loop never ends because set1 list is ever growing. 
2) `Approach 2` updates set1 ***after*** all the elements in set1 are processed. Am I on the right track in understanding the difference between two approaches? Also, can I consider `[ s + [n] for s in set1]` as a list resulted from the following pseudo code?

```
tmp = []
for s in set1:
   tmp += [s + [n]]
```

Comment: Yes. That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're modifying the list you're iterating on in the `for s in set1` loop.  This could be avoided by using copy() to ensure that you iterating on a separate instance of the list : `for s in set1.copy()`. you could also constrain the length of the loop: `for s in set1[:len(set1)]`

Answer (score 1):

I think your two approaches are not equal.

The approach two is "extend `set1` after compute the list". So the equivalent to approach 2 should like below:

```
set1 = [[]]
num = [1,2,3]
for n in num:
    tmp = []
    for s in set1:
        tmp += [ s + [n] ]
    set1 += tmp
print(set1)
```

Why you approach 1 hang? It's not hang, it's looping forever, because you extend your list while traverse it.

```
    for s in set1:
        set1 += [ s + [n] ]
```

Every time you get next element of `set1`, your `set1` get longer.

It is really a bad idea to change the element while traverse it. Don't do that. Creating a middle variable like your pseudo code is more safe and clear.